# stop a threading.Thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, task

the following code:

```
import time
import threading
tasks = dict()

class newTask(object):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        [setattr(self, x, kw[x]) for x in kw]
        self.object_ret()

    def object_ret(self): return self

def task_create(name, timeout, function):
    task = newTask(**{
        'timeout': int(timeout),
        'function': function,
        'start': time.time()
        })
    def set_timeout(v):
        while True:
            if (time.time() - v.start) > v.timeout:
                v.function()
                v.start = time.time()
    tasks[name] = threading.Thread(target=set_timeout, args=(task,))
    tasks[name].start()

def stop(x):
    #stops the thread in tasks[x]
```

is a simple task system that i am using for minor tasks such as pings and timeouts. This works for my needs but if i ever wanted to stop a ping or task that was running, there is no way for me to do so. Is there a way for me to delete or stop that thread that i created using any means possible? I do not care if it is bad or messy to do so, i just want it stopped.

Comment: The function `set_timeout` is a closure that has access to `task` and the parameters passed to `task_create`. Also, creating a dictionary and then converting it with `**` into named function parameters kind-of defeats the goal of keyword argument. Calling a function that just returns `self` as last action in `__init__` doesn't clarify your code either. Lastly, busy-looping is very expensive CPU-wise. That said, you need to tell your thread to terminate, using e.g. a condition, and then wait for it to terminate. You should be able to find examples on the 'net easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following:

1. In your newTask.**init** function, add a line "self.alive = True"
2. In the set_timeout function, replace "while True:" with "while v.alive:"
3. Store newTask objects in your "tasks" dictionary, not thread objects.
4. The stop(x) function has one line: "tasks[x].alive = False"

This will cause the thread to die when you call stop(x), where x is the thread's name.  It provides a mechanism that allows a thread to die without killing it in some bogus way. I know you said you don't care, but you really *should* care if you want your multithreaded programs to work.

Second suggestion: read Ulrich Eckhardt's comment carefully and take it seriously; all of his points are well taken.

Comment: actually made something similar to this and found a roundabout solution.

Comment: and this is only for a simple ping system for staying connected to a couple of clients so i do not think it will matter too much if a thread is removed improperly.

Answer (score 0):

Signal handler:::

```
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
  print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
  tasks[name].stop()
  sys.exit(0)
```

in the main script, register the handler:::

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.pause()
```